# SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'id' doesn't have a default value in Laravel 6

Tags: mysql, laravel, insert

Here, I'm trying to to insert the data in the database but for some reason I am not able to insert the data in the database. This is the error:

SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'id' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `stages` (`code`, `name`, `description`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (32, dfs, vc, 2020-04-14 06:02:57, 2020-04-14 06:02:57))"

My code are here:

StageController.php

```
<?php


namespace App\Sys\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Sys\Model\Stage;

class StageController extends Controller
{

    public function index(Request $request)
    {  
        $per_page = $request->per_page ? $request->per_page : 5;
        $sort_by = $request->sort_by;
        $order_by = $request->order_by;
        return response()->json(['stages' => Stage::orderBy($sort_by, $order_by)->paginate($per_page)],200);
    }

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $location= Stage::create([
            'code' =>$request->code,
            'name' =>$request->name,
            'description' =>$request->description
        ]);
        return response()->json(['stage'=>$stage],200);
    }


    public function show($id)                                                                                                                                                           
    {
        $stages = Stage::where('code','LIKE', "%$id%")->orWhere('name','LIKE', "%$id%")->orWhere('description', 'LIKE', "%$id%")->paginate();
        return response()->json(['stages' => $stages],200);
    }



    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
       $stage = Stage::find($id);
       $stage->code  = $request->code;
       $stage->name  = $request->name;
       $stage->description  = $request->description;
       $stage->save(); 
       return response()->json(['stage'=>$stage], 200);
    }

    public function destroy($id)
    {
        $stage = Stage::where('id', $id)->delete();
        return  response()->json(['stage'=>$stage],200);
    }

    public function deleteAll(Request $request){
        Stage::whereIn('id', $request->stages)->delete();
        return response()->json(['message', 'Records Deleted Successfully'], 200);
    }
}
```

Stage.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Sys\Model;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Stage extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = [];
}
```

My migration file:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateStagesTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('stages', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->uuid('id')->primary();
            $table->string('original_id',36)->default('0')->index();
            $table->string('code',10)->index()->nullable();
            $table->string('name',100);
            $table->string('description',200)->nullable();
            $table->char('created_by',36)->index();
            $table->char('edited_by',36)->index()->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->foreign('created_by')->references('id')->on('users');
            $table->foreign('edited_by')->references('id')->on('users');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('stages');
    }
}
```

Comment: you need to generate `id` for inserting.

Comment: @TsaiKoga Can you please tell how can I do that????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For laravel 5.6+ you can use `Str::uuid()` to generate the uuid string;

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
...
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $uuid = Str::uuid()->toString();
        $location= Stage::create([
            'id' => $uuid,
            'code' =>$request->code,
            'name' =>$request->name,
            'description' =>$request->description
        ]);
        return response()->json(['stage'=>$stage],200);
    }
```

For below laravel 5.6, you can use `Ramsey\Uuid\Uuid`;

```php
use Ramsey\Uuid\Uuid;
...
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $uuid = Uuid::uuid1()->toString();
        ...
        return response()->json(['stage'=>$stage],200);
    }
```

Or you can write an boot method for generating uuid to creating, Eloquent will automatically set `id=uuid` for every create method. If there are many models with primary key uuid, you can write a trait and use this trait in each models.

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
...
class Stage extends Model
{

    /**
     * Boot function from laravel.
     */
    protected static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        static::creating(function ($model) {
            $model->{$model->getKeyName()} = Str::uuid()->toString();
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case i didn't add that field into fillable in my Model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Flight extends Model
{
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = ['name'];
}
```

Answer (score -2):

i just added to id in phpmyadmin a auto_increment

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).